# Customizing javax.swing.JFileChooser to include an additional JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to include an additional (optional) JTextField in the FileChooser, allowing the user to fill it in while choosing the file rather than giving them an additional prompt after they make their choice. Has anybody attempted something similar and found a working solution?

My target result would look something like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/lVMd6]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documented](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#accessory) way to add controls to a `JFileChooser` is via the [setAccessory(JComponent)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setAccessory(javax.swing.JComponent)) method.

```
JTextField field = new JTextField("Hello, World");
JPanel accessory = new JPanel();
accessory.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
accessory.add(field);

JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setAccessory(accessory);
int ret = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
```

However, this will layout the new control on the right of the dialog (exact positioning is probably locale-dependent).

To locate the component to the position you want it, you'll probably have to walk the component graph and manipulate it. This would be a very fragile approach and you may be better off just building your own dialog.

This could incorporate a file chooser:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO - wire into something
    System.out.println(e);
  }
});

JTextField field = new JTextField("Hello, World");

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(chooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.add(field, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Years and years later...

I could archieve this quite easily using this method:

1. Get the layout manager of the file chooser (which is a BorderLayout).
2. Using the layout manager, get the SOUTH component from the file chooser, save its reference and remove it from the file chooser.
3. create a new panel containing whatever you want as well as the original SOUTH component. I personally use a vertical BoxLayout. I also add a Box.Filler of (1,12) between the components.
4. Set the new panel as the SOUTH component of the file choose.
5. Voilà !

   ```
   JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

   BorderLayout chooserLayout = (BorderLayout) chooser.getLayout();
   JPanel chooserSouthComponent = (JPanel) chooserLayout.getLayoutComponent( chooser, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
   chooser.remove( chooserSouthComponent );

   JPanel newSouthComponent = new JPanel();
   newSouthComponent.setLayout( new BoxLayout( newSouthComponent, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS ) );

   JPanel utility = new JPanel();
   JTextField field = new JTextField("Hello, World");
   TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( "title" );
   utility.setBorder(title);
   utility.add( field );

   Dimension fillerDimension = new Dimension( 1, 12 );

   newSouthComponent.add( utility );
   newSouthComponent.add( new Box.Filler( fillerDimension, fillerDimension, fillerDimension ) );
   newSouthComponent.add( chooserSouthComponent );

   chooser.add( newSouthComponent, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

   chooser.showOpenDialog( null );
   ```